# widgets appear in a weird position until the screen is touched in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I just started with wxpython and I had built a code that writes a message with a number he gets from pubsub but when I get to that panel that specific message appears in a weird position until I change the resolution of the application and then it comes back

the code of the panel is:

```
class ChangeNumStationPanel(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent, frame):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                      size=(1000,800),
                      style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

    self.frame = frame
    self.parent = parent
    self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.LIGHT_GREY)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

   
    # current num box
    currentNum_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    self.currentNum_Text = wx.StaticText(self, 1, label="")

    currentNum_box.Add(self.currentNum_Text, 0, wx.CENTER, 5)

    # subscribe to pubsub to know current num of station per message
    pub.subscribe(self.change_current, "current_changer")

   
    sizer.Add(currentNum_box,0, wx.CENTER, 5)

  

    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.Layout()
    self.Hide()


def change_current(self, currentNum):
    """

    :param currentNum: current number of station per message
    :return: changes the label according to the number
    """

    self.currentNum_Text.SetLabel("Current number of station per message: " + currentNum)
```

the text that appears weird is "Current number of station per message: "
I'm sorry if I don't explain it quite well , please if you didn't understand ask me and I will try to help you understand so you can help me :)

how the message is presented:[image]

you can see the text is not in the center... but after I move the application around the text magically goes back to the center.

Comment: "appears weird" is not satisfactory: Say what you expect and what you actually see. You should also provide a minimal working example - get rid of all extraneous widgets and logic and just show what is essential to describe the problem. Often you will find that by getting down to the essentials you see the solution yourself

Comment: is it possible for me to show a picture here?

Comment: Yes! click o the *image* button

Comment: I added the picture..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the Layout() method on the panel after you have updated the text in the label. Until that is called the panel does not realise that its contents have changed and the sizers need re-caclulating

```
def change_current(self, currentNum):
    """

    :param currentNum: current number of station per message
    :return: changes the label according to the number
    """

    self.currentNum_Text.SetLabel("Current number of station per message: " + currentNum)
    self.Layout()
```

Comment: thanks it worked. but I have another panel it happened on , and adding the layout doesn't fix it, this time it's with a listbox, I am adding the code to the question please see if you can help

Comment: Do not ask two questions in one posting - ask your second question separately - it is probably a different issue. Please take my advice and post a MINIMAL working example - no extraneous widgets or logic (What is back-box in your code?). MWEs encourage responders to look at your question and try it out, otherwise they have to spend time working out what is essential and getting around the loose items that you have left in the code

Comment: thank you very much for the critic I will upload the other question separately and try to keep the minimal working example